# No se revoca privilegio ORA-01927: cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Con el usuario `SYS` se requiere revocar el privilegio `EXECUTE` de la tabla `AWRRPT_HTML_TYPE` sin embargo al ejecutar la sentencia

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON AWRRPT_HTML_TYPE FROM PUBLIC;
```

Muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> ORA-01927: cannot REVOKE privileges you did not grant

Se le otorgo el privilegio a la tabla con la sentencia:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON AWRRPT_HTML_TYPE TO PUBLIC;
```

Posteriormente se ejecuto:

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON AWRRPT_HTML_TYPE FROM PUBLIC ;
```

Y el mensaje que salio fue el siguiente:

> Revoke succeeded.

Pero al consultarlo

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE='PUBLIC' AND TABLE_NAME  = 'AWRRPT_HTML_TYPE';
```

**El privilegio continua.**

Version Oracle: `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0`

Comment: No deberías tener ningún problema en revocar el permiso con el usuario SYS. Sabes con qué usuario se realizó el primer GRANT?